# JavaScript - innerHTML Mult. Ids

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to javascript and am trying to fill to multiple divs by ID.

So far I have:

```
function run() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
    obj = JSON.parse(xhttp.response);

    for (var i = 0; i <= obj.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("posttitle"+i).innerHTML = obj[i]['title'];
    };

    for (var i = 0; i <= obj.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("posttext"+i).innerHTML = obj[i]['content'];
    };

    }
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://xxxx", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

HTML Setup

```
<div id="post0">
    <div id="posttitle0"></div>
    <div id="posttext0"></div>
</div>

<div id="post1">
    <div id="posttitle1"></div>
    <div id="posttext1"></div>
</div>
```

I can fill in the div for poststext[i] or posttitle[i] individually but when I run them together only the first only in the function works/fills in the Ids. What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Well your elements are numbered starting at 1 but your loop starts at 0. Have you checked the developer console for errors?

Comment: Updated. I miscopied that piece of HTML from code but I still doesn't want to add to both divs.

Comment: The first thing to learn is how to open the browser's error console. The error messages are printed there. It helps a lot in debugging things like this.

Comment: The problem is that the URL you're using doesn't exist: ```http://xxxx => ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED```

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira Surely you're joking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe its because you have <= which will try to grab a non existent element.

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("posttitle"+i).innerHTML = obj[i]['title'];
    document.getElementById("posttext"+i).innerHTML = obj[i]['content'];
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this and remove the ";" after the for

```
for (var i = 0; i <= obj.length; i++) {
document.getElementById("posttitle"+i).innerHTML = obj[i]['title'];
document.getElementById("posttext"+i).innerHTML = obj[i]['content'];
}
```